# Eclipse-AndroidEmulator doesn't apply changes of the project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, debugging, reload

I am currently developing an Android app with Eclipse Indigo (including Android plugin).
Everything was fine in the beginning. Then I made some changes and saw that the debugging perspective doesn't apply any of the changes. It always loads the same outdated version.

Restarting debug-perspective doesn't help.
Cleaning the project doesn't help.
Relocating the workspace or restarting Eclipse or the computer doesn't work either.

I once could load the whole new project by completly deleting everything (including Eclipse, Android plugin etc.) and reinstalling. But this is not an option for every time I wanna try out a new method.

Funny thing: if I write some text in the EditText-fields the text will still be there when I restart the debugging.

Any ideas how I can fix this problem to get the actual project?

Comment: Welcome at SO! So when you make a change in the layout it doesn't show up in the emulator? Have you tried to uninstall the older app before uploading the new version?

Comment: Thanks for the help.
I found the answer now.
I was in the debugging-modus with a virtual device - so deinstalling wasn't necessary...
But your comment gave me a hint I could create a new device...

And there was the Solution for my problem: creating a device with snapshot deactivated
(head->desk)

Comment: Don't hesitate to answer your own question and write what you found it. (Don't forget to accept it then) There will always be someone else having the same problem :)

Comment: You should not need to create a new emulator.  If you clean the package, it should definitely install the new build, unless something has broken in the adb connection into the emulator (that has been known to happen) or there is an error in the eclipse plugin's means of installing apps (also been known to happen).  At any rate, uninstalling the app from the settings menu of the device should work, and be much faster than starting up a brand new emulator.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solution: Create a device with snapshot deactivated.
It was on auto-activate in my version of android sdk.